# Sleeping beauty problem - why is it not 1/2?

Tags: probability

The problem is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_Beauty_problem

The solutions given for heads when waked are 1/2 or 1/3.  I can easily understand 1/2 and I present my reasoning below.  Is there a similar simple reasoning for 1/3?

As I understand it, a single trial is from Sunday to Wednesday.  During this trial, either the beauty is woken once (if heads on Monday) or twice (if tails on Monday).

Let's suppose there are 4 trials, that means 4 coin tosses on Monday.  Assuming a fair coin, 2 are heads, 2 are tails and the beauty wakes 4 times on Mondays.

For the 2 tails on Monday, the beauty has 2 more wakes on Tuesday.  Assuming a fair coin again, 1 is heads, 1 is tails.

So in total, 4 trials, 6 wakings, 3 heads, 3 tails.  So I get 1/2.

How does one get 1/3 using reasoning as simple as presented above?